# Empty list returned by Gio.FilenameCompleter().get_completions("/usr/bin/abr")

Tags: python, pygobject, linux-mint-21

Operating system: Linux Mint 21 Cinnamon. The python3.11 code:

````
'''```bash session
~ $ which abricotine
/usr/bin/abricotine
```'''
import gi # gi.version_info # (3, 44, 1)
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
import gi.repository # ['GLib', 'GModule', 'GObject', 'GdkPixbuf', 'Gio', 'Notify']
from gi.repository import Gio
objFilenameCompleter = Gio.FilenameCompleter()
ListOfCompletions = objFilenameCompleter.get_completions("/usr/bin/abr")
print(ListOfCompletions)
````

The appropriate libraries: `python3-gi` and `gir1.2-gtk-3.0` according to Synaptic Package Manager are installed.

Why am I getting an empty list as result in spite of the fact that there is a completion available?

**Can someone confirm the described behavior of returning of an empty list instead of a list with available completions?**